# Create an array in an ini file

Tags: arrays, ini

I'm programming in vb.net and I need to access information from an ini file. There is also some information that I need to insert into the ini file manually so that the program can access it. For example, I need an array `Extensions` to contain a set of possible file extensions for my program to loop through. How do I manually insert this into an ini file (ie just typing, without using a program)? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct syntax for an array, you can place whatever you like as value.
So you could choose whatever syntax you want, for example: *Extensions=.ex1,.ex2,.ex3*
and in your code you would parse (for this example split) the INI key's value as you need.

The syntax I used was like the following: *Extensions={.ex1,.ex2,.ex3}*
Also I created [an INI library](https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini) that would enable me to easily manipulate with that value syntax.
For example:

```
Dim ini As New IniFile()
ini.Load("My Extensions.ini")

Dim extensions As String()
If ini.Sections(0).Keys("Extensions").TryParseValue(extensions) Then
    For Each extension In extensions
        Console.WriteLine(extension)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! That's how I ended up doing it. I was just hoping there was some kind of array syntax to make things easier.